# Find locations of raster maximum within polygons: Basin Delineation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, hydrology, catchment-area

I'm trying to identify the Location (lat/lon) and upstream area of every raster point that flows into the Arctic Ocean (there are a lot so it has to be fully automated).  I'm starting with the following rasters:

- Flow Direction
- Accumlated Flow Area

My approach so far has been to use the above rasters to create a delineated basin shapefile.  From there I was hoping I could use the shapefile to look at the Flow Accumulation Raster and identify the location of the maximum value in each basin.  In terms of output, I just need a table that shows [Basin#, Longitude, Latitude, UpstreamArea] for every basin.

I've already looked at [How to find the locations of the highest values in a raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13289) but I don't know how to restrict the raster to only the area bounded by the polygons in the shapefile]

**Using: ArcGIS10, Python, etc.*

Comment: For those familiar with the hydrology tools, I'm essentially trying to find exactly 1 pour point for every basin, regardless of its size.  If I use the basin shapefile the input to Snap Pour Point, I get a pour point for every raster grid cell.  Hence why I'm apraching this outside of the Hydrology tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with after trying a number approaches using ArcMap tools.  My python skills are in their infancy but it works (although it took about 36 hours to loop over the 110,000 basins.

1. Create lat/lon arrays that correspond to the basin and flow area files.
2. Loop over each basin, finding the maximum value and location indices in each
3. Find the lat/lon at each index location.
4. Write out.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   from osgeo import gdal

   #Load input Rasters (Basin Mask and Accumulated Upstream Area)
   #Input rasters need to be the same size
   f1 = gdal.Open("/pour_points/basins.asc")
   f2 = gdal.Open("/pour_points/source_area.asc")
   basins = np.array(f1.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
   areas = np.array(f2.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
   basins = np.ma.masked_values(basins,-9999)
   areas = np.ma.masked_values(areas,-9999)

   #Extract raster information (dimensions, min,max, etc)
   width = f1.RasterXSize
   height = f1.RasterYSize
   gt = f1.GetGeoTransform()
   res = gt[1]
   minx = gt[0]
   miny = gt[3] + width*gt[4] + height*gt[5]
   maxx = gt[0] + width*gt[1] + height*gt[2]
   maxy = gt[3]

   #Make arrays of lats and lons
   lons = np.linspace(minx,maxx-res,num=width)
   lats = np.linspace(maxy-res,miny,num=height)
   #Make arrays of same dimensions as input arrays of lat/lon values
   x,y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

   #Setup basin in/out arrays
   basin_ids = np.arange(np.min(basins),np.max(basins))
   #Test basins = basin_ids = np.array([57087,53728,55400,37250,60966,71339])

   basin = np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='i')
   max_area =  np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='i')
   x_outlet = np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='f')
   y_outlet = np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='f')
   min_x = np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='f')
   max_x = np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='f')
   min_y = np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='f')
   max_y = np.zeros(len(basin_ids),dtype='f')

   #Loop over every basin id, finding the maximum upstream area [and location]
   #and record the basin#,longitude,latitude,area
   for i,j in enumerate(basin_ids):
       #print 'i = ',i
       basin[i]=np.int(j)
       x_basin = x[np.nonzero(basins==j)]
       y_basin = y[np.nonzero(basins==j)]
       max_area[i] = np.int(max(areas[np.nonzero(basins==j)]))
       max_ind = np.argmax(areas[np.nonzero(basins==j)])
       x_outlet[i] = x_basin[max_ind]
       y_outlet[i] = y_basin[max_ind]
       min_x[i] = min(x_basin)
       max_x[i] = max(x_basin)+res
       min_y[i] = min(y_basin)
       max_y[i] = max(y_basin)+res

   #save the list of pour points as a comma seperated text file
   # This file is directly importable into arcgis for validation purposes
   out_file = 'arctic_pour_points.txt'
   with file(out_file,'w') as outfile:
       outfile.write('OID,longitude,latitude,basin_area,min_lon,min_lat,max_lon,max_lat\n')
       np.savetxt(outfile,(np.array([basin,x_outlet,y_outlet,max_area,min_x,min_y,max_x,max_y]).T),delimiter=',')
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that there is only 1 pixel per polygon that has a maximum value.

**1. Find Maximum Value**

> ... use the shapefile to look at the Flow Accumulation Raster and
>   identify the location of the maximum value in each basin.

To solve this task (find the maximum pixel value in each polygon) you can use [Zonal Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/).

in_zone_data = your polygon file

zone_field = basin number

in_value_raster = flow accumulation raster

statistics_type = MAXIMUM

**2. Convert basin polygon to raster**

pixel value = basin number

**3. Find location of the maximum value**

Use  [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Con/009z00000005000000/) to find the location of the maximum in each basin.

```
con ( <raster result from step 1> == <raster flow accumulation>, <raster from step 2>, 0)
```

The result raster contains one pixel for each basin. The pixel value shows the basin number.

**4. Convert raster to point**

convert result raster from step 3 to point file (only for pixel values not 0)

**5. calculate lat/lon for result from step 4**

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I also need to find the raster grid location of that maximum which is why I haven't been able Zonal Statistics.  Also, the shapefile is quite large so it would be best if I could use a scripting aproach where I can loop over the basin polygons.

Comment: You're about one-eighth of the way there: you have found the *value* of the maximum. To obtain the location, you need to go further. There are several approaches. One way is to create a zonal maximum *raster*--not a table--and compare that to the original DEM. This gives a 0-1 grid showing where the maxima occur. Use this to pick out the values in a grid of x coordinates, another grid of y coordinates, the flow accumulation grid, and a grid of basin IDs. Output these values as a table.

Comment: @sea_hydro: I edited my first answer while whuber makes a comment with an other aproach.